# Running flurry for a java server running on Ubuntu

Tags: java, flurry

I have a java server running car pool services on an EC2. I am using Flurry on my Android and iOS apps, but I could not find a way to run Flurry on the java server. All questions on stackoverflow for this particular case, have been answered for Android (I wonder why).

Has anyone tried to run flurry on their java server, or Java EE or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported at all. It would be very difficult to run the Android SDK with a Java server-side app since it depends on the Android libraries.

Comment: Obviously, thats why I was wondering if there was a java jar out there.

Comment: Ok, I can't help you there. We don't support this and I don't know of anyone doing it. (disclaimer: I work on the Android SDK at Flurry)

Comment: Do you know of any other analytics api's for java like flurry ?

Comment: Any updates on this? Has flurry started support for Server Side analytics in java?

Comment: @MichaelMassey I no longer work for Flurry. You should get in touch with the support team (support@flurry.com) to figure out if Flurry has started supporting this use case or if there is another way to achieve what you need.

Comment: @spacemanaki Thanks. I got an answer from them and server side analytics are not yet supported.